# Discharging an assumption for a theorem

Tags: proof-verification, logic

So it's my understanding that theorems do not rely on an assumption set. However, this theorem that I have come across seems like I will have to make at least one undischarged assumption.

$$├ (P \rightarrow Q) \lor (Q \lor R)$$

My initial approach was to use arrow introduction, so assume P then eventually discharge it once I had gotten Q. But I just don't see how I can get Q.

The rest of the theorem I can get using wedge introduction once I have one of the sides, I just don't see a way to get them.

Comment: Are you sure this is correct as written (and not, for example, $(Q \implies P) \lor (Q \lor R)$)? Without further assumptions, this is not always true.

Comment: In general, you are right: a "theorem" of *propositional calculus* must be a tautology and its proof must end without undischarged assumptions.

Comment: Specifically, the above formula is **not** a tautology, and thus you cannot prove it. This means that a valid derivation of it must have some undischarged assumption; foe example : $R$. In fact : $R \vdash (P \to Q) \lor (Q \lor R)$.

Answer (score 1):

As noted above, this "theorem" is *false*: making $P$ true and $Q$ and $R$ false results in $(P\rightarrow Q)\vee (Q\vee R)$ being **false**.

---

Separately, it's also worth noting that a theorem *with* hypotheses can be turned into a theorem *without* hypotheses:

- If $\varphi_1,...,\varphi_n\vdash\psi$, then $\vdash (\varphi_1\wedge ...\wedge\varphi_n)\rightarrow\psi$; this is the [deduction theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deduction_theorem).
- What about if we have $\Gamma\vdash \psi$ where $\Gamma$ is *infinite* (so we can't take the conjunction of everything in $\Gamma$)? Well, *proofs can only involve finitely many propositions*, so there is some finite $\{\varphi_1,...,\varphi_n\}\subseteq\Gamma$ such that $\varphi_1,...,\varphi_n\vdash\psi$; and now we're in the situation above.

*In a previous edit I mentioned the [compactness theorem](https://www.cs.rice.edu/~vardi/comp409/lec23.pdf) in the context of the second bulletpoint above. This was a slip-up on my part: the compactness theorem is about $\models$, not $\vdash$. Of course they're [actually equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completeness_(logic)), but this question is about $\vdash$ instead of $\models$ and $\vdash$ is "finitary" by definition; so compactness isn't relevant here.*